# How to set different (if) parameters for the same number in a list?

Tags: if-statement

- I don't even know how to format this paragraph right haha

Hi there I'm completely new to Python.
I was wondering if I have a list
how do I take the output of a first if command and use on the next

Example
L= [23, 91, 0, -11, 4, 23, 49]

for i in L:

if(i > 10):

print(i * 30)
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrYfA.png)

I also want to check if the output of this number is an even number if so (+6) -- for the output of that
if number is not equal to -11 I want to add 10.

So I got 23 > 10= (23*30 = 690) // 690 is an even number ( 690 + 6=696) // it not equal to -11 so (696+10= 706).

How do I do this for every number on the list? Excuse my lack of knowledge it's literally my first python class and my first exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```
L= [23, 91, 0, -11, 4, 23, 49]

for i in L:
    if i > 10:
        num = i * 30
        if num % 2 == 0:
            num += 6
            if i != -11:
                num += 10
        else:
            pass
        print(num)
```

output:

```
706
2746
706
1486
```

Comment: Yes really close, but output should have 7 numbers, as I want this to work for every number in the list. Not only the 4 numbers in this case 23, 91, 23, 49 which are greater than 10

Comment: Because if >10 will only get 4 numbers， 0, -11, 4 is not greater than 10, so the if statement will not hold